# Click the circle after hovernig to direct to a url

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/qd2o38fp/1/

I want the user to be able to hover over the circle, and then click the circle itself to be directed to another link. (not the text when hovered)

```
.ch-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    content: url(www.yahoo.com);
}
```

I tried to put

```
content: url(www.yahoo.com);
```

but this makes the text disappear for some reason.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply implement it as an anchor tag link (`<a href...>`) in your markup?

Comment: You can't put hyperlinks in a `content`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to click it, it must be a link:

```html
<a href="//www.yahoo.com" class="ch-info">
  <h3>See Portfolio</h3>                
</a>
```

Just display it as a block, and your current code will work:

```css
.ch-info {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.ch-grid {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.ch-grid::after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.pulsarwallpapers.com/data/media/3/Alien%20Ink%202560X1600%20Abstract%20Background.jpg);
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(63, 147, 147, 0.8);
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 45px 0 0 0;
  height: 140px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 242, 34, 0.8);
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.ch-item::before {
  content: "P";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ch-grid">
  <li>
    <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
      <a href="//www.yahoo.com" class="ch-info">
        <h3>See Portfolio</h3> 
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

extending Oriol's you could also use `clip-path: circle(110px at center);`
to limit :hover selection

```css
.ch-grid {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.ch-grid::after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  
}
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.pulsarwallpapers.com/data/media/3/Alien%20Ink%202560X1600%20Abstract%20Background.jpg);
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(63, 147, 147, 0.8);
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 45px 0 0 0;
  height: 140px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  clip-path: circle(110px at center);
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 242, 34, 0.8);
  clip-path: circle(110px at center);
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 clip-path: circle(110px at center);

}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
 
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.ch-item::before {
  content: "P";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ch-grid">
  <li>
    <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
      <a href="//www.yahoo.com" class="ch-info">
        <h3>See Portfolio</h3> 
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```